# Connect Office 365 Account with Enterprise Web using Azure AD

Tags: azure, adfs

My name is Apri and I am new to this forum.
I want to ask about the authentication token sharing carried out at Office 365 with the company website. Can anyone help me? The problem is I have searched several forums but still have not found a solution to my problem.

thanks.

Best regards,

Apri

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this form. Please go through Microsoft document [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/) for more information on your requirement.